# KMeans for Sentence Embeddings

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, k-means, sentence-similarity

## **K-MEANS Clustering b/w 2D NUMPY ARRAYS**

I have been looking for a solution for a while and I can sense there must be something silly I might be missing so here goes.
I have obtained sentence embeddings after training an embedding layer using Keras Sequential Layers.

*Dummy Example*

Let's say we have embeddings which looks like this:

```
Sentence 1 : np.array ([[6, 2], [3, 1], [7, 4], [8, 1], [5, 4], [9, 3], [5, 1]])

Sentence 2 : np.array ([[2, 5], [5, 7], [6, 5], [3, 1], [1, 1], [6,2], [2, 1]])
```

Basically, in a file with several sentences, I would want such sentence embeddings to be clustered so that similar sentences are clustered together.

I know this is the method we would use to cluster 1d arrays

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

I tried this:

```
x = np.array([ [[6, 2], [3, 1], [7, 4], [8, 1], [5, 4], [11, 3], [5, 1]] , 
               [[6, 5], [8, 1], [7, 4],[8, 1], [5, 4], [11, 3], [5, 1]] ])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0).fit(x)
```

which throws **ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.**

Is it even possible to do k means clustering on such data or is there any other methodology I should follow?

One solution and the only one I can think of is to Average the Sentence Embeddings and use np.squeeze to squeeze the dimension of each sentence to a 1D ARRAY before clustering but it would mean losing all the positional information of the words in a sentence.

*"I am a dog"  would be same as  "Am I a dog"* which is wrong

Comment: flatten your sentence embedding.

Comment: @Quang Hoang , thank you for this. Exactly what I was missing.

Comment: The way you are preserving positional information is too strict and you're better off averaging the word vectors. As it is you can only deal with sentences of the same length, and the same word in different positions won't be considered similar.

Comment: @polm23 Do you mean there could be worse results because of this strictness? I think it would always provide better results in text similarity recognition if I cluster the sentence embeddings without averaging than as compared to the averaging the individual embeddings and then clustering

Comment: I mean, it depends on your definition of similarity, but averaging word vectors is a standard baseline. See "A Simple but Tough-to-Beat Baseline for Sentence Embeddings"  https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Simple-but-Tough-to-Beat-Baseline-for-Sentence-Arora-Liang/3f1802d3f4f5f6d66875dac09112f978f12e1e1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly suggested by QUANG HOANG in the comments, the idea was to just **flatten** the dense sentence embedding matrix.

As needed, this would also keep the positional information about the words intact!

```
sent1 = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[1, 3], [7,5], [8, 1]]))
sent2 = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[3, 2], [4, 2], [2, 2]]))
sent3 = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 7], [3, 5]]))
sent4 = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 6], [3, 5]]))

X = np.array((s1,s2,s3,s4))

print (X)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3, 7, 5, 8, 1],
       [3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5],
       [1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.array([ [[6, 2], [3, 1], [7, 4], [8, 1], [5, 4], [11, 3], [5, 1]] , 
               [[6, 5], [8, 1], [7, 4],[8, 1], [5, 4], [11, 3], [5, 1]] ])
```

With reference to this, I am just guessing that the problem is that the scikit-learn expects 2d NumPy arrays for the training dataset for a fit function but the dataset you are passing in is a 3d array so you need to reshape the array into a 2d.